# Checking the method caller's field in C#

Tags: c#, methods, field

```
class Dog
{
 public void Bark()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("<Name_Of_Dog> just barked!")
  }
}
```

---

```
static void Main()
{
  Dog Spike=new Dog();
  Dog Mike=new Dog();
  Spike.Bark();
}
```

Now I want the console output to be: "Spike just barked!"
How can I do that?

Comment: Create a string property called "Name" in your class and assign the name manually. Do **not** use variable names to hold logic.

Comment: Simply not possible use Name property as suggested

Comment: You wouldn't want to check for the name of the variable.  The same object can be referenced by multiple variables with different names, or it could be in a collection and it would have no unique name of its own.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault It is not possible with reflection too. If you believe yes **prove it**. You can do only opening up the `IL` using `Mono.Cecil` or something

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yeah deleted the comment a few minutes ago, I forgot for a moment he used the variable name, not class name.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault So, Without your comment my comment looks floating. Probably me too have to remove my comment

Answer (score 0):

Use a property or field instead:

```
class Dog
{
   string Name
   public void Bark()
   {
     Console.WriteLine("{0} just barked!", Name)
   }
   public Dog(string name)
   {
     this.Name=name;
   }
}

static void Main()
{
  Dog Spike=new Dog("Spike");
  Dog Mike=new Dog("Mike");
  Spike.Bark();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of a variable is used by developers. It is used to communicate, to reveal why this variable exists, what it does and how it is used. Business logic should have absolutely nothing to do with variable names.

In this situation : `object potato = new Object()`, it is not because I named my object potato that it automatically becomes one. In your example, using dog names like this only indicates to developers that this Dog instance is named Spike, not that the actual object it represents is a dog named Spike.

What you need, is to define the characteristics of your objects via `properties` or `fields`.
For your situation, you need a field called Name. Why not a property? Because objects are like spies, they want to keep everything hidden from the whole world. Since you're not using the name elsewhere in the application, restrain the scope at class level :

```
class Dog
{
    private readonly string name;

    public Dog(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void Bark()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} just barked!", name);
    }
}
```

And the main :

```
Dog Spike = new Dog("Spike");
```

With a property, it would look like this :

```
class Dog
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void Bark()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} just barked!", Name);
    }
}
```

And the main becomes:

```
Dog Spike = new Dog { Name = "Spike" };
```